# Unable to access the application in LAN , if XAMPP installed in other than in C drive

Tags: php, apache, xampp

We installed Xampp server in D drive (Windows7 OS). We have been able run the application which was deployed in that server (ex: `localhost:80/sampleApp`). But we are unable to access that application ,from other System in LAN using IP address. (ex: `192.168.1.4:80/sampleApp`) . So please let me know if there is any other configuration required.

Comment: Check if the firewal is activated.

Comment: execute in cmd "telnet 192.168.1.4 80" to test access

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine XAMPP like WAMPServer comes with the assumption that you are using it to develop locally. Therefore the httpd.conf file will have something like this to control which ip addresses Apache is allowed to accept connections from, and by default it will just be the PC running Apache, like this :-

```
#Apache 2.2 syntax
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1

#Apache 2.4 syntax
Require local
```

So you need to allow access from other ip addresses i.e. you local lan. So try

```
#Apache 2.2 syntax
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1 192.168.1

#Apache 2.4 syntax
Require local
Require ip 192.168.1
```

Note: using ony the first 3 of the 4 quartiles allows access from any ip in that subnet